# web scraping with python ==$0 content is not available with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the water temperature of a lake from the local [website](https://www.goitzsche-tourismus.de/goitzsche-bitterfeld/specials/172-wassertemperatur) with beautifulsoup.

The resulting source code (via show source code in the Chorme Browser) or content by scraping with beautifulsoup is empty.

[html source code out of the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a67aZ.png)

```
url = 'https://www.goitzsche-tourismus.de/goitzsche-bitterfeld/specials/172-wassertemperatur/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

txt = soup.find("div", {"id": "pegel"}).get_text()
print('content:', txt, 'should be here')
```

result: `content:   should be here`

In the Chrome Developer Tool - console I get the correct result, if I type `$0`.

[use the developer tool console - result is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poiNr.png)

Question: How I get the temperature values?
Question: Why don't I see the values in the "basic" source code?

Thanks for some hints

Comment: That is because the content of that div is creating by a javascript script and beautiful soap can not run js scripts of the page. The real API for getting that information is something like:` https://pegel-muldestausee.de/mwget.php?API=f51099a5a49870bcb5d0b3292243051897ace618&2&callback=jQuery112405427758147583336_1577734500510&_=1577734500511`. So It's better to find out a way to getting data from the real API instead of scrapping that page.

Answer (score 3):

I answered something [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59505869/1708751) earlier.

Basically that site is loading in the base code for the site, and loading in the temperature values via. Javascript. And their code calls another API which contains that data.

You can mimic and probably utilize it too (ethically should get your own API key) and parse the [JSON result](https://pegel-muldestausee.de/mwget.php?API=f51099a5a49870bcb5d0b3292243051897ace618) instead.

The response as of this post I received was:

> ```
> {
>     "WWM-002 Pegelturm": {
>     "Zeit": "30. Dec 2019 15:00 Uhr",
>     "Pegel": "74.64",
>     "Temperatur": "5.25"
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you thousand times. To learn more - where you find the link to the JSON result? This could be useful for an other website with water temperatures, where I have to press a key to see the results (will be probably an other question)

Comment: You can accept this answer if it helped you. As far as how I found the link; in Chrome, I opened the DevTools -> Network tab, put in "api" in the filter, and looked at all the requests and responses; found the one that has the temperature information in it; and used that URL.