# BeautifulSoup cannot parse through html tag marked with =$0

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

"=$0" indicates the tag as the last selected Dom node, which means that all that html is added later via javascript which makes the tag look empty when parsing through it with beautiful soup. [This](https://mplayer.me/default.php?id=MTc3ODc3) is the website I am referring to, and I want to get the src from the video tag from `<div class = "jw-wrapper jw-reset"> =$0`
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmxxZ.jpg shows proof of the video tag on the web page.
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59535949/web-scraping-with-python-0-content-is-not-available-with-beautifulsoup) asks the same question but in the response the user shows a json result and tells us to parse through it. However I do not know how to implement that in my case.

Could I use a json result to grab the video tag, if yes how ? Or is there some other method I can use ?

EDIT>>
This is my code:

```
DRIVER_PATH = '/path/to/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get("https://mplayer.me/default.php?id=MTc3ODc3")
h1 = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "video")
print(h1.text)
driver.quit()
```

The output is
DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
[Then a blank line]

Answer (score 1):

You can't extract the src URL directly using BeautifulSoup because it's not in the HTML code returned with requests. So, you need to parse the HTML and Javascript before using it with BeautifulSoup. You can find Javascript parsing packages with simple Google search.

However, I would suggest to use Selenium instead for this work as it will use real browser to run JavaScript code and get your src URL.

Comment: @Boros Just sharing the error won't help. Share the code along with error. How am I supposed to know what's wrong with your code with this error message?

Comment: Just added that